# Rails assets, css, javascript all broken on production mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

i am using rails 4.2 and developing my rails app with windows 7 64 bits,
everything work fine on development mode, but once i tried to run my app on production mode, my app layout, css and javascript all broken,
i believe it has something to do with asset pipeline, but i don't quite understand, kindly give me some help.

here is my asset structure under

```
vendor/assets
 - public_assets
   - font
   - img
     - bg
     - favicon
     - images
         - proteam
     - png
         - ualanding
     - portofolio
         - thumbnail
         - fullsize
   - css
   - js
   - sass
   - vendor
      - bootstrap
         - css
         - fonts
         - js
      - font-awesome
         - css
         - fonts
         - less 
         - scss
      - jquery
      - magnific-popup
      - ninja-slider
      - scroolreveal
   - vid
 - Static_Dev
   - assets
      - img
         - flags
         - avatars
     - css
     - js 
          - libs
          - views
     - fonts
```

and i called my assets in these files :

```
admin.css
admin.js
public.css
public.js
```

i also added this to my assets.rb :

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( public.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( admin.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( admin.js )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( public.js )
```

and this to application.rb

```
config.assets.paths += Dir["#{Rails.root}/vendor/public-assets/*"].sort_by { |dir| -dir.size }
config.assets.paths += Dir["#{Rails.root}/vendor/Static_Dev/*"].sort_by { |dir| -dir.size }
```

here is my browser error log :

```
http://localhost:3000/stylesheets/public.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:3000/javascripts/public.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:3000/assets/img/logo.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:3000/assets/img/png/UA-Landing/Img-UALanding1.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:3000/assets/img/png/UA-Landing/Img-UALanding2.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:3000/assets/img/png/UA-Landing/Img-UALanding3.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:3000/assets/vid/URBAN%20video.mp4 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
(index):372 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(anonymous function) @ (index):372
base.js:6943 GET http://localhost:3000/uploads/house/thumbnail/8/Pensive_Parakeet.jpg 404 (Not Found)h.Ja @ base.js:6943g5 @ base.js:4017mma @ base.js:4007b9 @ base.js:4335psa @ base.js:4349W8 @ base.js:4330W8.create @ base.js:7301(anonymous function) @ www-embed-player.js:507g.De @ www-embed-player.js:507oi @ www-embed-player.js:505g.Zb @ www-embed-player.js:498(anonymous function) @ www-embed-player.js:540
base.js:6943 GET http://localhost:3000/uploads/house/thumbnail/1/Penguins.jpg 404 (Not Found)h.Ja @ base.js:6943g5 @ base.js:4017mma @ base.js:4007b9 @ base.js:4335psa @ base.js:4349W8 @ base.js:4330W8.create @ base.js:7301(anonymous function) @ www-embed-player.js:507g.De @ www-embed-player.js:507oi @ www-embed-player.js:505g.Zb @ www-embed-player.js:498(anonymous function) @ www-embed-player.js:540
base.js:6943 GET http://localhost:3000/uploads/apt/thumbnail/144/Pensive_Parakeet.jpg 404 (Not Found)h.Ja @ base.js:6943g5 @ base.js:4017mma @ base.js:4007b9 @ base.js:4335psa @ base.js:4349W8 @ base.js:4330W8.create @ base.js:7301(anonymous function) @ www-embed-player.js:507g.De @ www-embed-player.js:507oi @ www-embed-player.js:505g.Zb @ www-embed-player.js:498(anonymous function) @ www-embed-player.js:540
```

i run this command :

> rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production

and result error like this :

```
C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\urbanace\urbanacecode>rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV
=production
I, [2016-09-19T16:18:29.470690 #13608]  INFO -- : Writing C:/Users/lenovo/Docume
nts/urbanace/urbanacecode/public/assets/public-78c00ecc416b598bae03765242c333f88
e2db37a2d83217a99d53e02d1e5d9de.css
I, [2016-09-19T16:18:29.525693 #13608]  INFO -- : Writing C:/Users/lenovo/Docume
nts/urbanace/urbanacecode/public/assets/public-78c00ecc416b598bae03765242c333f88
e2db37a2d83217a99d53e02d1e5d9de.css.gz
I, [2016-09-19T16:18:38.402201 #13608]  INFO -- : Writing C:/Users/lenovo/Docume
nts/urbanace/urbanacecode/public/assets/admin-529cbf47908b1b0636fcd9023a0f6acf3c
1bd78078f3feca7863f077f17ddf2b.css
I, [2016-09-19T16:18:38.402201 #13608]  INFO -- : Writing C:/Users/lenovo/Docume
nts/urbanace/urbanacecode/public/assets/admin-529cbf47908b1b0636fcd9023a0f6acf3c
1bd78078f3feca7863f077f17ddf2b.css.gz
rake aborted!
ExecJS::RuntimeError: undefined: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: eof (undefined)
```

please advice what i missed here?

Comment: what exactly is not working.

Comment: layout, css and javascript all not found. in case u need it, i updated my question with browser error log.

Comment: Did you precompile your assets before you started the server in production mode?

Comment: i thought i only need to add precompile to assets.rb? mind to show me what command do i need to run? i am quite new to rails.

Comment: @Teoulas oh i google and precompiled my assets, but got some error, updated my question with compile error logs.

Comment: Put  these lines 'Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( public.css )' in your application.rb instead of your assets.rb

Comment: @luissimo moved to application.rb, still no luck,

Answer (score 0):

Open up config/environments/production.rb and make sure the following option is set to true:

```
# Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
config.assets.compile = true
```

Then run:

```
rake assets:precompile --trace RAILS_ENV=production
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: i tried this, asset got compiled, but when i try to access my app, it throw "We're sorry, but something went wrong.

If you are the application owner check the logs for more information." also checked error log, this line caused the error,  ActionView::Template::Error (undefined: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: eof (undefined)):

Comment: What is your host? if it's heroku did you run  ` heroku run rake db:create` and ` heroku run rake db:migrate`

Comment: @Johan sorry for late response, my host is windows 7 64 bit, i am trying to run in production mode in my computer, if success, later i will upload my app and run in centos 6.